# Dirties context upon TestRule

Tags: java, spring, junit

''''

```
import org.junit.rules.TestRule;
import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.junit.runners.model.Statement;

public class RetryRule implements TestRule {
    private int retryCount;

    public RetryRule(int retryCount) {
        this.retryCount = retryCount;
    }

    public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
        return statement(base, description);
    }

    private Statement statement(final Statement base, final Description description) {
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {

                // implement retry logic here
                for (int i = 0; i < retryCount; i++) {
                    try {
                        base.evaluate();
                        return;
                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        //  System.out.println(": run " + (i+1) + " failed");
                        System.err.println(description.getDisplayName() + ": run " + (i + 1) + " failed.");
                    }
                }
                System.err.println(description.getDisplayName() + ": giving up after " + retryCount + " failures.");
            }
        };
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SomeTestClass {

@Rule
private RetryRule rule = new RetryRule(3);

@Test
public void test() {...}
```

}

I have lot of integration tests written in Junit4 which may sometimes fail due to Awaitibility.await(...) mechanism. I found that i can use this TestRule interface to restart them couple times and try to make them pass. But the tring is i need to restart the context also like @DirtiesContext, but ONLY when the test failed - entered catch block inside RetryRule.
Any ideas?